# How to receive phone number from web link with tel: scheme

Tags: c#, windows, url-scheme, tel

In my Windows`.NET Application, I need to receive a number from web browser when a button been clicked on our web page.
We investigate and find out if I put this element on our html web page:

```
<a href="tel:0218980">0218980</a>
```

. . ,It will opens an arbitrary application. So we will select our .NET Application in this point, and the number would be received by it.
What should I implement in C# to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: so.. to put short, you want to **extract** the phone number inside `href="tel:0218980"`? you can use `regex` or a html library (something like `HtmlAgilityPack`).

Comment: No ,. . . on click event, web browser shows a list of applications for call. I want to develope that caller application.

Comment: oh, you will need to associate `tel` with your app, its done via registry (see FLCL answer). the phone number will then passed as command line argument to your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo need to make a handler that consumes command line arguments and to register it [via Windows Registry](https://superuser.com/questions/1112229/cant-change-tel-protocol-handler-in-windows-10).

(caller.exe there is a placement for your app)

Comment: What is a console argument? All process types can have command line parameters...

Comment: @Anders, as in `caller.exe %1` will turn into `caller.exe 0218980`. the `%1` is the argument. the app gotta handle the passed arguments via the (starting) main method (e.g. on c# its `static void Main(string[] args)`, the `args` are the arguments).

Comment: @BagusTesa Of course but "console argument" (before the edit) is not a thing. To be doubly pedantic, %1 is not the argument, that is just part of the protocol registration. `ShellExecute` will convert the %1 before the new process is started.

Comment: you are absolutely right. however, people do make mistake and i do admit this answer assumes a lot background knowledge from asker.

Comment: Yes, and linking to SuperUser instead of MSDN is not ideal